# Copy data attribute into QGIS layer (not external link)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, excel

I need to copy data from an external file .xls to a layer.
I have to share a project with only shape file (no .xls).

Now the layer has normal data attribute with join

I do not understand that request, but that's it

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understanding what you're asking. Could you describe your workflow and outcome more detailled?

Comment: I have an external DB joined to a shape. I need to manage the project without the xls DB, I need to store the excel data into the shape file. Then I will delete the xls DB

Comment: That sounds feasible. So, where are you stuck/what is your question?

Comment: Make the join and re-save the Shaepfile, the joined attributes will be included in the new Shapefile.

Comment: I can join the external data but I am not able to copy into the project. When I delete the excel file I lose data attribute

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto that's it. Maybe the question was stupid, but if you reply with your info I will accept it

Comment: @Ale I think the phrasing was a little difficult to follow, but not a stupid question. It's easy to solve if you know how, but not really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you make the join to the excel file. If you re-save the Shapefile. (Right click on it, Export, Save features as..) The newly saved Shapefile will have the joined attributes saved onto it.